# How to select variables from this heatmap?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, seaborn, heatmap, random-forest

[Here This is My problem.
In this heatmap i did eliminate some variables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1UvI.png)

This is after elimination of some variables

My Question Is:
 Is There Any correlated variables there in 2nd image?
 Is My process of Elimination of varibles is right?
 do I Still need to eliminate variables from the second image?

Help Me Out This........

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no co-related variables in the image.

As per the image, ur approach to eliminate variables seems to be correct.

No, u need not eliminate any more variables.

Additional Tip: If u want to reduce number of independent variables, study about 'Principal Component Analysis'. It significantly reduces number of variables by making new axes showing maximum variance.